# getting total number of records in an excel file using jxl

Tags: java, jxl

I am trying to read a .xls excel file using jxl. I want to get the total number of records in the file. For this, I was using the getRows() method. But it displays the value as 8 when there are 6 total records. My aim is to read all the records from the excel file and store in a database.

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow, please post your code to get help from the SO Community

Answer (score 0):

Please give some code.. and the excel sheet to understand the problem in depth. 
http://www.javaworld.com/article/2074940/learn-java/java-app-dev-reading-and-